Copying records to the next empty row
I implemented a VBA function with the following goals:

Copy the values from range (A8:F400) in the 'Single Column' tab to columns (AA2:AF) in the 'Index' tab.
The criteria for copying. There is a value in column D (not null).
Paste the values and number formats in the first available row in the Index tab.

The data set is copied to the appropriate columns, but pasted in the 20,000 - 80,000 row range, bypassing 1000s of empty rows. I executed the script multiple times, but the pasting keeps bypassing any empty cells and adds the data set further down the my Index sheet tab.
Sub MoveListToIndex()

'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    
Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Submit the List?", vbYesNo, "Submit List")
    
If Answer = vbYes Then

    Dim D As Range

    Set D = Worksheets("Single Column").Range("D7:D400")

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Single Column")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Index")

    For Each cell In D

        If cell.Value <> "" Then

            '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column D
            lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    
            '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column AA
            'Offset property moves down 1 row
            lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

            '3. Copy & Paste Data
            wsCopy.Range("A8:F400" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
            wsDest.Range("AA" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

        End If
    Next cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "The List has been Successfully Added!"
 
End If
End Sub

Dummy Spreadsheet



You may have some content where you don't expect it.  What's the value of lDestLastRow?  If you go to the last cell in Col AA on the destination sheet and press Ctrl+Up where does that take you?

Wonder whether wsCopy.Range("A8:F400" & lCopyLastRow).Copy needs to be wsCopy.Range("A8:F" & lCopyLastRow).Copy

Put a watch on lCopyLastRow and lDestLastRow, then step through the code

@nkalvi - thanks, when I attempted to change the wsCopy.Range as mentioned, the records are pasted but also looped, essentially pasting the same data set many times, duplicating the data. It seems an issue with how i've setup the For Loop and IF statement

@TimWilliams, thanks, I attempted to clear out all records in Column AA, then I pressed Ctrtl+Up as indicated and it takes me to the top header row (1).

@JarvisDavis, yes - there are two issues I think. You could change the method to 1) set lCopyLastRow based on last non-empty cell in D (perhaps by looping or by using CountA) 2) Without looping, use wsCopy.Range("A8:F" & lCopyLastRow).Copy. Currently you're copying the range for each non-empty cell in column D.

Here's an alternative to try:
Sub MoveListToIndex()

'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to Submit the List?", vbYesNo, "Submit List")
    
        If Answer = vbYes Then

Dim D As Range

Set D = Worksheets("Single Column").Range("D7:D400")

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Single Column")
  Set wsDest = Worksheets("Index")

'1. Non-empty in D - header row + row to the first cell D7
lCopyLastRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(D) - 1 + 7
lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row



  '2. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("A8:F" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
  wsDest.Range("AA" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats


'Debug.Print "A8:F" & lCopyLastRow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "The List has been Successfully Added!"
 
End If
End Sub



Append Non-Empty Rows


Starting with D8 on sheet Single Column, combines each row (A:F) where the cell in column D is not empty into a unioned range. Then it copies the unioned range to the next available row (AA:AF) of sheet Index in one go.
The next available row is determined using the Find method with xlValues which ignores blank cells that are not empty. Also, it doesn't require choosing an always-populated column (in this case column A or AA) since the search is performed on AA2:AF1048576 considering all columns.

Sub SubmitList()

    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Submit List"
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Single Column"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "D8"
    Const SRC_COPY_COLUMNS As String = "A:F"
    
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "Index"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "AA2"
    
    ' Let the user choose to continue.
    
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult:
    Answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to submit the list?", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, PROC_TITLE)
    If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Reference the source lookup (single-column) range ('slrg')
    ' and the source copy range ('srg').
    
    ' Reference the source sheet.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim slrg As Range, sRowsCount As Long
    
    ' Reference the source lookup range.
    With sws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        sRowsCount = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If sRowsCount < 1 Then ' no data found
            MsgBox "No data found in ""'" & sws.Name & "'!" _
                & .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Address(0, 0) & """!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set slrg = .Resize(sRowsCount)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the source copy range.
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(SRC_COPY_COLUMNS)
    
    ' Loop through the rows ('sRow') of the ranges and for each empty cell
    ' in 'slrg', combine the corresponding row ('srrg') of 'srg'
    ' into a unioned range ('surg').
    
    Dim surg As Range, srrg As Range, scell As Range, sRow As Long
    Dim IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    For Each scell In slrg.Cells
        sRow = sRow + 1 ' next row
        ' When an empty cell is found in 'slrg',...
        If Not IsEmpty(scell.Value) Then
            ' ... the corresponding row of 'srg',...
            Set srrg = srg.Rows(sRow)
            ' ... is combined into (added to) 'surg'.
            If IsFirstFound Then ' after first
                Set surg = Union(surg, srrg)
            Else ' first
                Set surg = srrg
                IsFirstFound = True
            End If
        End If
    Next scell
    
    ' Since the condition is 'not empty' and 'sRowsCount > 0',
    ' no need to do 'If IsFirstFound Then...' because something was found.
    
    ' Reference the destination cell ('dcell').
    
    ' Reference the destination sheet.
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME)
    ' Reference the first (possible) destination cell.
    Dim dfcell As Range: Set dfcell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Reference the destination processing range (e.g. 'AA2:F1048576').
    Dim dprg As Range:
    With dfcell
        Set dprg = .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, surg.Columns.Count)
    End With
    
    ' Reference the bottom-most non-blank cell in 'dprg'.
    Dim dcell As Range:
    Set dcell = dprg.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    
    ' Reference the destination cell.
    If dcell Is Nothing Then ' no existing data found
        Set dcell = dfcell
    Else ' existing data found
        Set dcell = dcell.EntireRow.Columns(dfcell.Column).Offset(1)
    End If
    
    ' Copy (append) 'surg' to 'dcell'.
    
    surg.Copy
    dcell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "The list has been successfully submitted!", _
        vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
     
End Sub

